# How does the wording "for each" work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Some cards in magic has something happen *for each {something}*. For instance: [Alive // Well](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369041&part=Alive) makes you gain 2 life for each creature you control. Tapping [Selvala](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382357) adds one green mana to your mana pool, and you gain 1 life for each non-land card revealed.

How is this life gained: all at once or "one bit" at a time? Say I tap Selvala and 1 land, and 2 non-lands are revealed: do I gain 2 life, or do I gain 1 life two times? Would [Ajani's Pridemate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376241) have one or two +1/+1 counters placed on it if I had it in play at that point?

Comment: nice question. My instinct says it is only one event. but can't find any rules that back that up

Comment: That's what I'm inclined to think as well, but from a conversation with someone it seemed like they thought otherwise.

Comment: Don't spells/abilities only add one effect to the stack unless they explicitly say otherwise? So in this case, the effect is "gain 2 life for each", so it's one effect and you're gaining 2*n life at one time.

Comment: @Ellesedil It's not just the stack that matters. When you resolve a spell or ability on the stack, you don't group all of its effects up into one and then determine triggers. If a card specifies two things separately (e.g. for some strange reason "gain 2 life, then gain 4 life") they happen separately, in that order. So the question is whether "for each" means, "gain a quantity of life equal to 2 per creature" or "for each creature, one at a time, gain 2 life".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *How is this life gained: all at once or "one bit" at a time?*

**Count the verbs.** There is only one instruction to gain life, so all the life is gained simultaneously.

> 608.2e Some spells and abilities have multiple steps or actions, denoted by separate sentences or clauses, that involve multiple players. In these cases, the choices for the first action are made in APNAP order, and then the first action is processed simultaneously. Then the choices for the second action are made in APNAP order, and then **that action is processed simultaneously**, and so on. See rule 101.4.

[Life Burst](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Life%20Burst) has two instructions to gain life (two verbs), so there would be two life gain events.

---

> *Would Ajani's Pridemate have one or two +1/+1 counters placed on it if I had it in play at that point?*

Since all life is gained simultaneously and it all came from the same source, there is only one life gain event, so it would only trigger once.

Note that if you simultaneously gained life from multiple sources, that would count as multiple life gains events, and the ability would trigger multiple times.

> 118.9. Some triggered abilities are written, "Whenever [a player] gains life, . . . ." Such abilities are treated as though they are written, "Whenever a source causes [a player] to gain life, . . . ." If a player gains 0 life, no life gain event has occurred, and these abilities won’t trigger.

That applies very narrowly to life gain. It doesn't apply to taking damage. For example, if [Boros Reckoner](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boros%20Reckoner) is simultaneously dealt damage from two sources, its ability will only trigger once. It would need the wording of [Nested Ghoul](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nested%20Ghoul)'s ability to be triggered twice.

Comment: I don't think this answer helps clear up the ambiguity. You don't provide a rule for "count the verbs". The very question is in whether or not "for each" counts as having multiple verbs.

Comment: Note that a valid English and mathematical reading of "for each creature, gain a life" when there are 2 creatures is: "gain a life. Gain a life." This is how a computer would read and execute a program written that way. While I don't think that's the intent of the card or the rules, there is still not a rule defining "for each".

Comment: @GendoIkari I think the rule referenced is sufficient because it doesn't reference "verbs" but "separate sentences or clauses". "Gain 2 life for each creature you control" is a single verb clause, so by that rule all of the life gain "is processed simultaneously". And since it's a single source adding a certain amount of life simultaneously, it's a single event. And your point about a computer is irrelevant: I could just as easily write a program that specifies `add 2*(number of creatures)` as `for creature in creatures: add 2`.

Comment: @GendoIkari, Yes, I did. I just gave a tip that you can count actions by counting verbs.

Comment: @ikegami No, that's not what I meant. You said "that would be the case". I'm not sure if by "that" you mean "multiple life gain events" (as in the first section) or "only one life gain event" (as in the second section). Especially because the note is with the second section, but the correct answer is the first one (which I provided a rules reference for).

Comment: @murgatroid99, Gendolkari's math comment was in response to a paragraph I had in my answer I removed before he even made his comment because it didn't make things any clearer.

Comment: @ikegami Now I think that all parts of your answer relevant to the question are correct, but what source do you have that simultaneous damage from multiple sources counts as a single damage event?

Comment: @murgatroid99, It's not in the rules that it doesn't do more than specified. As per the English definition, "is dealt damage" doesn't check who did it or how much they did. Source of rule interpretation: Previous discussions on Wizards' Rules Q&A forum. It can also be inferred from the presence of the two different wordings.

Comment: @ikegami OK, based on rulings I found, you're right about that one.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Also, 118.9 wouldn't be necessary if "dealt damage" and "dealt damage by a source" were the same thing, because that would mean "gains life" and "gains life from a source" would already be the same thing.

Comment: @user1873, 1) Re "Maybe quote the section in the CR that deals with effects", 608.2 is too large to quote. I quoted the subsection that's relevant to the answer.

Comment: @user1873, 2) Re "Then you might want to mention spells than deal with LKI due to zone changing, and needing to look back in time at the game-state before and after an effect." ???? I don't see how LKI has any relevance.

Comment: @user1873, 3) Re "I don't buy the 'count your verbs' argument." Then give me a counterexample. I would be interested in what other kinds of words denotes the taking of actions.

Comment: @user1873, 4) Re "Do you have an emample of a one-shot effect that uses multiple verbs and causes you gain life in two separate events?" Of course not. Each verb is an effect. Like I said, count the verbs.

Comment: @user1873, You had asked about a *single* effect with multiple verbs. I did mention Life Burst in my answer, which has two verbs, thus two effects, and thus two events

Comment: @user1873, I don't see how 700.1 helps. (wtf is a "happening"?)

Comment: @user1873, I don't know what you're looking it, but 608.2 has nothing to do with APNAP. 608.2 explains how to resolve spells and abilities.

Comment: @user1873, Wall of Shards.... interesting. I'll have to bring this up at Wizard's Rules Q&A.

Comment: I was suggesting that 608.2g (which talks of getting an answer once if an effect requires it) is a better example than your 608.2e reference that **is about APNAP** order when effects involve multiple players.

Comment: @user1873, No, 608.2e is not about APNAP; it's about handling abilities with multiple steps or actions. It mentioned that each action is performed at once, which answers the OP's question. As for 608.2g, why do you bring up LKI again??? You've already agreed that LKI has nothing to do with the question! "getting an answer once if an effect requires it" doesn't help either.

Comment: 608.2g isn't about LKI, re-read it. Interestingly enough, **112.2c** An object may have multiple abilities. If the object is represented by a card, then aside from certain defined abilities that may be strung together on a single line (see rule 702, “Keyword Abilities”), each paragraph break in a card’s text marks a separate ability. [...] **And 603.2c** An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains multiple occurrences. [...] **Might lead you astray** Does it contain multiple occurrences because of "for each"?

Answer (score 6):

I contacted Wizard's MtG APAC Support last night. The response confirmed what we suspect: only one life gain occurs, but they didn't know any *specific* ruling about this either.

I think [Ikegami's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18060/5573) very soundly conveys the rules basis for it working this way, though.

For posterity, and for some level of official confirmation, here's the response from support:

> When Riot Control activates the life gain triggers as a single event meaning that Archangle of Thune will only activate once. So in the situation that you provided, when you cast Riot Control the following will happen: You will gain 3 life and each of your creatures will receive a single (1) +1/+1 counter. Now if the card was Ageless Entity that states: "Whenever you gain life, put that many +1/+1 counters on Ageless Entity." you would be putting three (3) +1/+1 counters on Ageless Entity since you would have gained that much life through Riot Control.
>
> I'm afraid that there isn't a specific ruling that would fit here, but the wording of the card itself describes what will happen.
>
> *(Ed: courtesies and administrative stuff omitted)*
>
> — Eric M.
> Online Response Crew
> Wizards of the Coast

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the comments, I can't find any rules that specify it but according to this similar example here http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3767486 it would only be one event. In the example it was actually two because of the wording of [Life Burst](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Life%20Burst), but the second instance on that card has also a "for each" wording that would only trigger one event.

Comment: Based on what though? Those people are just saying it happens once regardless of the "for each" calculation, but not citing anything, which is about the same as if you or I answered this saying "You only gain life once" and left it at that.

Comment: I find several questions on the web stating the same. I think it actual isn't covered by the rules, since I actually did a Ctrl+F on the comp rules for "gain" and also "for each" and found nothing. I guess it could only be settled by an actual judge then. I tried googling a similar question that is answered by a judge but unfortunately couldn't find one.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find anything either, but I'm pretty sure you're right: the wording does sound much more like "gain a quantity of life equal to..." than "count your creatures and every time you count one gain 2 life".

Comment: It might be like the word "deals" for damage events. Each instant of the word "deals" is one event. So I think Jefromi's comment is probably pretty close: Congregate means "Target player gains 2x life, where x is ..."

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs, See my answer. I provided the rule that does apply. You could argue the rule doesn't apply, but that would be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Just to clarify a little, even though I am not going to quote any rules, in this case simple logic will help.

If you have for example Ajani's Pridemate in play and you cast Well part of the Alive // Well card this is what happens.

Well on the stack resolves, the spell counts your creatures during its resolving process and gain you lives during one single event, there are not keyworded two or more instances to be resolved seerately. Ajani's Pridemate's abbility triggers and it gets 1 +1/+1 counter.

Comment: When other, much older answers have rules quotes and official confirmation from Wizards of the Coast, you might want to think twice before posting "It's common sense." This feels like noise.